# How to create a new ros topic for specific messages

Tags: rostopic, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topics in ROS are strongly typed. I need to publish and subscribe messages I have created for hector_uav_msgs folder but existing topics don't support them. How to start creating from scratch a new rostopic so my own messages can be applied?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218879/how-to-create-a-new-ros-topic-for-specific-messages/) by [Humberto Beltrao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20626/humberto-beltrao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do these help?

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humberto Beltrao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20626/humberto-beltrao/) on 2015-10-09**:
Thanks for your answer. However, my point is to publish/subscribe new message types. Summing up, a new topic where I can use the messages. Hector_quadrotor topics have their own messages and even inserting my new messages correctly in hector_uav_msgs, I haven't figured out how to pub/sub them yet

**Comment by [Humberto Beltrao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20626/humberto-beltrao/) on 2015-10-10**:
I have just figured out how to do what I was looking for using ros service idea. So thanks again, Gary!